# Как работать с char32_t в windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Я пишу для windows 10 и не использую сторонних библиотек. Использую char32_t для хранения массива символов. Я понимаю что выводить на консоль юникод не лучшая идея из-за кодовых страниц и ограничений шрифтов. Однако не смотря на это мне интересно возможно ли вообще вывести в консоль хотя бы частично.

---

Всё что я нашёл это приведение типа char32_t к wchar_t, что кажется работает с усечением
(char32_t - 4 байта в windows, wchar_t - 2 байта в windows)
Что конечно же не относится к Linux (стандарт говорит что wchar_t - 4 байта, а значит нет усечения)

---

- *Существует ли какой-то другой способ кроме приведения к wchar_t, в стандарте 20/23?*
- *Если такого способа нет, то как правильно конвертировать char32_t в wchar_t?*
- *Как правильно выводить, cout/wcout?*
- *Стоит ли вообще использовать именно char32_t?*

Comment: *"стандарт говорит что wchar_t - 4 байта"* Не говорит, насколько я помню.